# plot in python for theano LSTM

Tags: python, lstm

i'm trying to plot in LSTM python code below,but nothing happening,what can i do to fix it?(it's only the last of the code,lstm code is available on [deeplearning.com](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html))

```
       print 'Train ', train_err, 'Valid ', valid_err, 'Test ', test_err
    if saveto:
       numpy.savez(saveto, train_err=train_err,
                valid_err=valid_err, test_err=test_err,
                history_errs=history_errs, **best_p)

       print 'The code run for %d epochs, with %f sec/epochs' % (
       (eidx + 1), (end_time - start_time) / (1. * (eidx + 1)))
       print >> sys.stderr, ('Training took %.1fs' %
                      (end_time - start_time))

       plt.plot(numpy.array(max_epochs), numpy.array(test_err), 'b-')
       plt.xlabel('epochs')
       plt.ylabel('error')
       return train_err, valid_err, test_err


if __name__ == '__main__':
   # See function train for all possible parameter and there definition.
   train_lstm(
   max_epochs=10,
    test_size=500,
)
```

Comment: If by "nothing happening" you mean not even the first `print` statement in your code runs, then obviously the problem is somewhere *before* the code you provided. If that's not the case and your code does print something, please provide the output. And please fix the indentation in your post, as there's no way to tell if you have indentation issues in your code or in your post.

Comment: LSTM code runs and print results well,but for plot nothin shows!the out put of code is sth like normal without plot code,i mean if i delete plot code nothing changes,but i wanna plot results!